# Copy files and backup the existing + subdirectories

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a program to backup files from a particular folder, along with the files within the subfolders of the main folder to another backup folder.

This is part of the code I am trying to accomplish the goal, however I am getting backed up only the files from the main folder, and the subfolders are being copied entirely(all of the files in them).

```
  public static string[] Backup(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory, string backupDirectory)
    {
        DirectoryInfo diBackup = new DirectoryInfo(backupDirectory);
        DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

        List<string> dups = new List<string>();
        string[] fileNamesSource = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        string[] fileNamesDest = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> dupNS = new List<string>();
        List<string> dupND = new List<string>();
        List<string> BCKP = new List<string>();
        string replacement = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNamesDest.Length; i++)
        {
            string res = fileNamesDest[i].Replace(targetDirectory, replacement);
            dupND.Add(res);

        }


        foreach (var ns in fileNamesSource)
        {
            string res = ns.Replace(sourceDirectory, replacement);
            dupNS.Add(res);

        }

        var duplicates = dupND.Intersect(dupNS);

        string[] DuplicatesStringArray = duplicates.ToArray();

        foreach (var dup in DuplicatesStringArray)
        {
            string res = targetDirectory + dup;
            BCKP.Add(res);

        }

        string[] ToBeBackedUp = BCKP.ToArray();


        Directory.CreateDirectory(diBackup.FullName);

        // Copy each file into the new directory.
        foreach (FileInfo fi in diTarget.GetFiles())
        {
            if (ToBeBackedUp.Contains(fi.FullName)){ 

            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(diBackup.FullName, fi.Name), true);
            }

        }

        // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in diTarget.GetDirectories())
        {
            if (ToBeBackedUp.Contains(diSourceSubDir.FullName)) { 
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                diBackup.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
            }
        }
        return ToBeBackedUp;

    }
```

Any ideas of how can I copy only the files in the subfolders that exist in the "source" folder?

Also the CopyAll function:

```
public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {

        Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);

        // Copy each file into the new directory.
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {


                fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);


        }

        // Copy each subdirectory using recursion.
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way as
Much easier

```
//Now Create all of the directories
foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));

//Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", 
    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution: in your `CopyAll` method, load the `SearchOption.AllDirectories` argument to your `GetFiles` method:

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
}
```

Comment: The solution works, however the files are copied into the root directory /no subdirectory gets created/. I might be doing something wrong as I am new.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) along with `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to extract the files from the sub-folders as well:

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, *search pattern goes here*, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```